# Scope Change from Pure String Syntax to Hash Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following scope within a model:

```
class Office < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :money_pot
  has_one :fiscal_year, through: :money_pot
  has_one :money_type, through: :money_pot

  scope :order_by_fiscal_year_and_money_type, -> {
      joins(money_pot: [:fiscal_year, :money_type])
      .order("fiscal_years.end_date desc, money_types.short_name")}
end
```

This scope does work.  However: I would like to switch from the "pure string" syntax to the "hash" syntax within that `order` clause.  I am having trouble I think due to the fact that the `order` clause within the scope is on the associations.

Here is what I have tried but it didn't work:

```
scope :order_by_fiscal_year_and_grant_type, -> {
    joins(money_pot: [:fiscal_year, :money_type])
    .order(fiscal_years: {end_date: :desc}, money_types: {short_name: :asc})}
```

Here is the error it returns:

> Direction "{:end_date=>:desc}" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]

I have looked at the [ordering section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) and the [hash conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) section of the Active Record Query Interface Rails Guides.

How can I convert this scope completely into the hash syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I [have found](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order#1652-Ordering-on-associations-using-merge) to not using plain string is `merge`:

```
scope :order_by_fiscal_year_and_money_type, lambda {
  joins(money_pot: [:fiscal_year, :money_type])
    .merge(FiscalYears.order(end_date: :desc)
    .merge(MoneyType.order(:short_name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer!  Would you mind explaining why `lambda` is considered better than `->`?

Comment: @Neil it's just a "prefered" syntax, that Ruby community in the "person" of [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) decided to be conventional. Basically use `lambda` over `->` for multiline scope in Rails

Comment: @Neil I would definitely recommend you to install Rubocop and use it in your projects - you can sometimes even learn something, not to mention improvement in coding style you gain with it ;)